# Changing the voxel size of nifti files from 1.5 to 2mm

Tags: image-segmentation, imaging, voxel

I have done some segmentation via the cat12 tool which is set by default to 1.5mm of voxel size. Now I realized that I need the voxels to be 2mm. Is there a way to change the voxel size without having to rerun the whole segmentations? Thanks a lot

I have looked for ways to coregister my nifti files to 2mm space - but couldn't find any